# List all Azure resources for inventory report

Tags: powershell, azure

Sounds simple enough, but let me explain further. My company is in the Managed Services business, and every so often we have to take over existing Azure estates. We're looking for a solution that would spider through the users estate and list all their Azure resources (everything, not just IaaS, PaaS and SaaS as well).

So far with my Google searching and software trials these past few days, I've found there's little out there. For the ones that are, they only look at IaaS. I've seen a lot of PowerShell scripts out there that do the same thing, IaaS reports. However, I would like a topology view of all resources and 'some' details (all details would be great, but that might be a stretch).

I know of the PowerShell command Get-AzureRmResource, but to create a superscript that would list all the details of every resource would be painful. I've also seen the Logic App for **List resources by subscription** works quite well, much the same of the PowerShell command, but to expand upon that would be a huge amount of work.

Long story short, does anyone know of any **good** solution to list all resources per subscription? Anything that can integrate with Power BI would be a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

If `Get-AzureRmResource` is does not give enough information, then you can use `Export-AzureRmResourceGroup` to get the template used to create a service, containing the settings used to create the service, like this:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Export-AzureRmResourceGroup -IncludeParameterDefaultValue
```

The parameter `-IncludeParameterDefaultValue` will include the parameters used to create the serivce.

**Note**: this won't include all the settings made after the creation of the service, only the information used when creating it. I'm not aware of any way to get an exact snapshot of the state of the service at some given time, including all the settings it contains.

Comment: Interesting PowerShell command. This is like exporting the ARM template from the Portal. One true way to see what the current settings are to use the API: resources.azure.com. Would be nice to have an app that can gather all that and stick it in some form of DB to pick apart and link together, like Cosmos Graph DB